# When will xfce 4.10 available in official Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, official-repositories

I was wondering why, after about 4 months from the release of xfce 4.10, it is still not available in official Ubuntu repositories and when it will be available? I do not want to install it from ppa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XFCE 4.10 was released too late to be Included in the current LTS release.

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10) containing XFCE 4.10 states:

> *The first Xubuntu release to feature Xfce 4.10 will be Xubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal).*

The PPA is maintained by the actual Xubuntu developers, so I'd take it as pretty final. If you want XFCE 4.10 in *Precise* use the PPA.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/18105-xfce-410-official-ppa-for-ubuntu-1204

**XFCE 4.10 has an Official Xubuntu PPA now!**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10

sudo apt-get update
```

if you have the XFCE 4.10-pre installed

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you do not have it installed and want to install it

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```